# Trying to get images to upload to a folder

Tags: php

Hi I have an upload script that uploads images to a file, but I can not get to save in a file that isnt in the same folder as the php script.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move  
'/tmp/phpkiIfQ' to 'http://--Webaddress--/Logoimages/bug4.png' in 
/home/--host--/public_html/uploaded/upload3.php on line 48
```

Removed some details and replaces with "--relevant--"

Here is the code I have on line 48

```
"http://--WebAddress--/Logoimages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Any help would be great thanks,
Mikey

Thanks you to everyone who answered

Comment: I guess it is some permissions issue. Do you have the right to write in the folder you want to write the file ?

Comment: So please paste the return of the `ls -all` command to check if the perms are set right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
"../Logoimages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually using a HTTP URL as the location to move files to? That's probably where you're going wrong. Try using a local file path. If you need to go up and down the tree the pseudo directory .. will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move the file to a url - you need to move it to the location on disk which maps to that Url - eg `/srv/www/htdocs/Logoimages/somefile.png` (The exact path will depend on what flavour of linux you're running and how your sites are set up)

Also, make sure your website user has permissions to write to that folder

Comment: So sorry not amazing at php, so would that work if I put that into were I have    "http://--WebAddress--/Logoimages/"

Comment: You need to copy the file into the directory on the disk that has all the other files served from Logoimages